# GNU/Linux - Python3 - PySerial: How to send data over USB connection?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pyserial

I have 2 questions about Python3 and PySerial (serial module).

I must send data over USB port to my IC's stand-alone ATMega32. A possible snippet code:

```
import serial
data=serial.Serial(port, speed)

first_data=99.7 # Float point data.
second_data=100 # Only int data like 10, 345, 2341 and so on.
third_data=56.7 # Float data

ValueToWrite=????? # How to convert it?

send=data.write(ValueToWrite)
```

Now if I try to send "first_data" with "ValueToWrite=firts_data" I have this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Well. Reading documentation about method **write** (class **serial.Serial** - http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html) I see:

> Write the bytes data to the port. This should be of type bytes (or compatible such as bytearray or memoryview). Unicode strings must be encoded (e.g. 'hello'.encode('utf-8').

1. My first question: I don't understand how to send my float and int data. How to convert them into string?
2. My second question: I'd like to send data all together, a unique value like this:

   99.7F100S56.7T

In this case, using ATMega's Firmware, I can split and update data in the corresponding variables, when encountered "F" character for the first data, "S" character for the second data and so on.

How to do this in Python3 using pyserial?

Comment: you can probably simply send `data.write("99.7F100S56.7T")`

Comment: Thanks @njzk2 :  sorry for my poor explanation, but variables change in "quasi real time", every 0.5 seconds. My snippet code would be just a very simple example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. converting float, int or most other non-strings to strings by using the [string function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), e.g. in your case

`str(first_data)`

would output '99.7' (a string).

2. by using the [string format method](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#string-formatting), e.g.

`'{0}F{1}S{2}T'.format(first_data, second_data, third_data)`

would output '99.7F100S56.7T'

These strings you can use as parameters to serial.send

Comment: Yes, it works like a treat.

I used your suggestion then I used "strtok(char *str, const char delim)-like C" function in the firmware to separate every field.